# Spring or JSP shows several same error messages instead of one

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, message

I have next issue - JSP (or Spring) shows same error messages twice or even more times on Login/Register Pages. 
Why it can be? I haven't found same issue somebody had. Previously thanks.

I can't post pictures yet, so I've postet it here [pictures](http://postimg.org/gallery/22wn36ig/a250ba03/)

My **Login.jsp**

```
     <sf:form name="login"
      method="POST"
      action="${app}/login.do"
      modelAttribute="loginForm"
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">  

      <label for="login">Login:</label> 
      <br><input name="login" id="login" type="text" value=""/> <br>      
      <sf:errors path="login" cssClass="error"/>
      <br>
      <br><label for="password">Password:</label>
      <br><input name="password" id="password" type="password" value=""/> <br>
     <sf:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/><br>
     <br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
   </sf:form>
```

**LoginController class**

```
     @Controller
     public class LoginController {
     //Log4j
     private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

     public LoginController() {
     }

     @Qualifier("loginValidator")
     @Autowired
     private LoginValidator loginValidator;

     public LoginController(LoginValidator loginValidator) {
     this.loginValidator = loginValidator;
     }

     @InitBinder("loginForm")
     private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(loginValidator);  
    }

     @Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
     @Autowired
     private UserService userService;

     @Qualifier("roleServiceImpl")
     @Autowired
     private RoleService roleService;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView loginPage() {
     return new ModelAndView("login", "loginForm", new LoginForm());
     }



     @RequestMapping(value = "/login.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute("loginForm")
                              @Valid LoginForm loginForm,
                              BindingResult bindingResult,
                              HttpServletRequest request, 
                              HttpServletResponse response) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.trace("check  authentication!");

        String login = request.getParameter("login");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        new ModelAndView("login", "loginForm", loginForm);
        loginValidator.validate(loginForm, bindingResult);
        try {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return new ModelAndView("login", "loginForm", loginForm);
            } else {
                // If the user details is validated then redirecting the user to  
                welcome page,
                // else returning the error message on login page.
                User user = userService.authorization(login, password);
                if (user != null) {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
                    //Creating a redirection view to welcome page.
                    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("welcome", true);
                    return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
                } else {
                    bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("Invalid", "Invalid 
                     credentials. " + "Login or Password is incorrect."));
                    return new ModelAndView("login", "loginForm", loginForm);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in LoginController " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ModelAndView("login", "loginForm", loginForm);
        }
    }
```

**LoginForm class**

```
public class LoginForm {

    @NotBlank
    private String login;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

...Getter and Setters
```

**messages.properties file**

```
login.required=Login is required!!
password.required=Password is required!!
password.again=Passwords do not match   
name.required=Name is required
email.required=Email is required
email.correct=Not correct recording format, example XYZ@gmail.com
email.again=Emails do not match
```

Comment: You are also validating twice. Once automatically (due to the `initBinder`) and once in your code by calling the validate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @M.Deinum mentioned, you have validated the form twice. just remove this line:

```
loginValidator.validate(loginForm, bindingResult);
```

everything should be fine. since you have @Valid, you are using JSR-303 to validate your bean. You don't have to validate it again by calling the `validate()` method manually.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I thought it is one validation approach is so big. And if I want to use improved validator such as "regexp = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+$")" I should use this form?                                                 `loginValidator.validate(loginForm, bindingResult);`

Comment: @Devour, you mean you wanna validate the password with a regex?, then you can use `@Pattern` in the LoginForm.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I've already done in with validator class. Thank you everyone for help.